# Navigate to record Salesforce Mobile

Tags: salesforce1-app

I want to redirect a record detail page in sf1 when a hyper link is clicked.

Below is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sForce1Navigate() {
  if( (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && (sforce != null) ) {
   sforce.one.navigateToSObject("​recordId"​[, detail])
  }
  return false;
}
</script>


<apex:outputLink onclick="sForce1Navigate();" value="{!task.Id}">{!task.subject }</apex:outputLink>
```

When i see the url link after clicking, i see the 'apex' before the recordId and am getting an error.

apex/123456799njn

But i need to get rid off the 'apex' from url to navigate to record, else it treats it as a vf page.

How can i do this?

Comment: You're passin recordId as a String, try removing the quotes...

Comment: Actually looks like there's a few problems in your code - I can't see where recordId is being set at all in the JavaScript.  You could pass the ID with the function - ie onclick="sForce1Navigate('{!task.id}')" and then change your function definition to function sForce1Navigate(recordId) etc...

Comment: I tried the way you suggested and still the result is same alex..